# QGIS raster calculator using Python console

Tags: pyqgis, raster-calculator, qgis-python-console

I want to calculate sum values of many rasters (from input folder) in QGIS Python using raster calculator. When I run script, QGIS crashes:

> Windows fatal exception: access violation

```
import os
from qgis.analysis import QgsRasterCalculator, QgsRasterCalculatorEntry
from qgis.core import QgsRasterLayer

work_folder = 'C:/QGIS/input_rasters'

rasters = [file for file in os.listdir(work_folder) if file.endswith('.nc')]

entries = []

i = 0
for raster in rasters:
    i = i + 1
    raster_path = os.path.join(work_folder, raster)
    input_raster = QgsRasterLayer(raster_path, raster)
    entry = QgsRasterCalculatorEntry()
    entry.ref = f"'ras@{i}'"
    entry.raster = input_raster
    entry.bandNumber = 1
    entries.append(entry)
    
expression = " + ".join(entry.ref for entry in entries)
output = 'C:/QGIS/output.tif'
calc = QgsRasterCalculator(expression, output, 'GTiff', input_raster.extent(), input_raster.width(), input_raster.height(), entries)
calc.processCalculation()
```

When I rewrite to two rasters, code works, but I need to do it for many rasters.

```
import os
from qgis.analysis import QgsRasterCalculator, QgsRasterCalculatorEntry
from qgis.core import QgsRasterLayer

work_folder = 'C:/QGIS/input_rasters'

rasters = [file for file in os.listdir(work_folder) if file.endswith('.nc')]

entries = []

raster_path = os.path.join(work_folder, 'test1.nc')
input_raster = QgsRasterLayer(raster_path, raster)
entry = QgsRasterCalculatorEntry()
entry.ref = 'ras@1'
entry.raster = input_raster
entry.bandNumber = 1
entries.append(entry)

raster2_path = os.path.join(work_folder, 'test2.nc')
input2_raster = QgsRasterLayer(raster2_path, raster)
entry = QgsRasterCalculatorEntry()
entry.ref = 'ras@2'
entry.raster = input2_raster
entry.bandNumber = 1
entries.append(entry)

output = 'C:/QGIS/output/output.tif'
calc = QgsRasterCalculator('ras@1 + ras@2', output, 'GTiff', input_raster.extent(), input_raster.width(), input_raster.height(), entries)
calc.processCalculation()
```